# How to animate every single letter without the text size changing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make every single letter get bigger on hover. I got that animation but I want to get rid of the whole sentence to move. I tried using absolute positioning; it didn't work.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6d391kkd/).

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>
       <span id='let-1'>S</span><span id='let-2'>a</span><span id='let-3'>m</span><span id='let-4'>p</span><span id='let-5'>l</span><span id='let-6'>e</span>
       <span id='let-7'>T</span><span id='let-8'>e</span><span id='let-9'>x</span><span id='let-10'>t</span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        h1 {
            text-align: center; 
        }
        span {
            font-size: 3em;
        }
        div:hover span {
            animation: .3s letters forwards;
        }
        #let-2 {
            animation-delay: .1s;
        }
        #let-3 {
            animation-delay: .2s;
        }
        #let-4 {
            animation-delay: .3s;
        }
        #let-5 {
            animation-delay: .4s;
        }
        #let-6 {
            animation-delay: .5s;
        }
        #let-7 {
            animation-delay: .6s;
        }
        #let-8 {
            animation-delay: .7s;
        }
        #let-9 {
            animation-delay: .8s;
        }
        #let-10 {
            animation-delay: .9s;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes letters {
            from,to {font-size: 3em;}
            50% {font-size: 4em;}
        }
        @keyframes letters {
            from,to {font-size: 3em;}
            50% {font-size: 4em;}
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of animating the `font-size` property you could animate `transform: scale()`

```css
h1 {
            text-align: center;
            
        }
        span {
            font-size: 3em;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        div:hover span {
            animation: .3s letters forwards;
        }
        #let-2 {
            animation-delay: .1s;
        }
        #let-3 {
            animation-delay: .2s;
        }
        #let-4 {
            animation-delay: .3s;
        }
        #let-5 {
            animation-delay: .4s;
        }
        #let-6 {
            animation-delay: .5s;
        }
        #let-7 {
            animation-delay: .6s;
        }
        #let-8 {
            animation-delay: .7s;
        }
        #let-9 {
            animation-delay: .8s;
        }
        #let-10 {
            animation-delay: .9s;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes letters {
            from,to {transform: scale(1);}
            50% {transform: scale(1.3);}
        }
        @keyframes letters {
            from,to {transform: scale(1);}
            50% {transform: scale(1.3);}
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>
        <span id='let-1'>S</span><span id='let-2'>a</span><span id='let-3'>m</span><span id='let-4'>p</span><span id='let-5'>l</span><span id='let-6'>e</span>
     <span id='let-7'>T</span><span id='let-8'>e</span><span id='let-9'>x</span><span id='let-10'>t</span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working on FF/Linux, and in Chrome is still moving whole sentence (on some window width it breaks in 2 lines on hover)

Comment: Works fine in Chrome. Fails in Firefox.

Comment: It looks like Firefox cannot animate `transform` on inline elements. Adding `display: inline-block` seems to work.

Comment: @just95 now it looks perfect - nice answer I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float: left` on your `span` elements. But then you need to center the `h1` by taking its width and making `margin: auto`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nx8pL0m/)